# ajax check usersname in database

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

right now I'm working on my website where the ajax should check if the user exists in the database. and I'm almost finished but I have some problems with it says that it is not available. this is how the user admin is maintained in the database but is not admin user in the database and no matter what you will see it and say "not available".

hope that there are some who can help me to get solve this problem.

I've been into firefox and look with firebug or whatever it's called and I can not find any fault at all!.

What I hope to be clear / made
- That's why it considers whether it is right for the user exists in the database or not?.

What problem are present now and here it is
- Whatever it says that the username "not available". I want to help change this so that it is out on whether it exists or not

```
<tr>
<td>
<p>Brugernavn</p>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="brugernavn" id="brugernavn" onblur="CheckUserName(this.value)"/>
</td>
<td>
<span id="availability_status"/></div>
</td>
</tr>


function CheckUserName(username){
    if(username.length > 3){
        var url = "ajax_check_username.php";        
        var params = "brugernavn="+ username +"&rand="+Math.random();
        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open("POST", url, true);
        //Send the proper header information along with the request
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        http.send(params);
        http.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200 ){    
                var val = parseInt(http.responseText);
                var html=(val == 0) ? '<font color="Green">Tilgængelig</font>' : '<font color="red">Ikke tilgængelig</font>';
                document.getElementById('availability_status').innerHTML = html;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('availability_status').innerHTML = '<font color="#cc0000">Username too short</font>';               
    }       
}
```

**ajax_check_username.php** here from!

```
<?php
// bør ligge i en extern fil,bruges generalt til alle db opslag
function MySqlIConnOOP(){
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");    
    if (!$conn) {
        echo 'Der opsod en fejl.';
        exit();     
    }
    $conn->set_charset("utf8"); 
    return $conn;
}

// bør ligge i en extern fil, da man også bør checke det inden man opretter brugeren serverside, nogle kunne jo have pillet i JS
// retunerer 0 eller brugerens id (tal størrer end 0)
function IsUserCreated($mysqli, $username){
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `bruger` WHERE `brugernavn` = ? ")){
        /* bind parameters for markers */       
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);              
        $stmt->execute();       
        $stmt->bind_result($id);    
        $stmt->fetch();                     
        $status = ($id >0) ? $id : 0;
        $stmt->close();     
    }
    else $status = -1;
    return $status; 
}

$conn=MySqlIConnOOP();
$brugernavn = $_POST["brugernavn"];
$status = IsUserCreated($conn, $brugernavn);
echo ($status >0)? 1 : $status;
?>
```

Comment: Could you please rework your question. Not sure I understand : is "not available" = "Tilgængelig" ?

Comment: No. not available it here "Ikke tilgængelig" and accessible is this "tilgængelig"

Comment: Have you tried debugging by var_dumping the database query/result and looked at the firebug console the ajax response?

Comment: @sglessard So it is as you say to me right now tells me nothing. since I can not see how you believe it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I understand :

IsUserCreated PHP function returns an integer (> 0 if username found)

CheckUserName JS function checks the returning value :

```
var val = parseInt(http.responseText);
var html=(val == 0) ? '<font color="Green">Tilgængelig</font>' : '<font color="red">Ikke tilgængelig</font>';
```

Then if val == 0, "Tilgængelig" else (val != 0) is "Ikke tilgængelig".

If username exist, it will print "Ikke tilgængelig".
If username does not exist, it will print "Tilgængelig".

Isn't it a simple label edit?

```
var html=(val > 0) ? '<font color="Green">Username exists</font>' : '<font color="Red">Username does not exist</font>';
```

Comment: Yes it's true understanding of you :) but you're not eidt in it or what?

Comment: it has gotten better now but now it doing just about on it it will say that it says admin can create but admin can not create :-) I just need to build on it or what?

Comment: It works now and thanks for the help! You just know that you have made ​​my day better!